# Atualizar objeto json em uma coluna varchar

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Pessoal estou com um problema no Postgres, eu tenho uma coluna que é no formato `varchar` mas conforme uma necessidade tenho que colocar um objeto JSON salvo nele

```
{"value": "value", "value2": "value2"}
```

É possível atualizar apenas o `value2` por exemplo?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nas versões mais recentes do Postgres, existem, diversas funções para manipulação de [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Mas considerando que você precisa usar o tipo `VARCHAR` e atualizar apenas uma parte do JSON na coluna, sugiro a utilização de Expressão Regular.

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
   '{"value": "value", "value2": "value2", "value3": "value3"}', 
   '(?<="value2": )(null|\d+(\.\d+)?|"([^"]*(\\")?)*")', 
   quote_ident('New Value'), 
   'g')
```

No caso do `UPDATE`, ficaria assim:

```sql
UPDATE tabela
SET coluna = 
   REGEXP_REPLACE(coluna, 
      '(?<="value2": )(null|\d+(\.\d+)?|"([^"]*(\\")?)*")', 
      quote_ident('New Value'), 
      'g')
WHERE id = 123456
```

O uso da função `quote_ident`serve apenas para adicionar as aspas. Se for adicionar um valor numérico é só passar o literal direto.

Comment: deu certo daniel! valeu